# Has the "weapon durability bug" been fixed in both the original Dark Souls II and Scholar of the First Sin?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

A bug in Dark Souls II caused weapons to degrade at double rate when played at 60fps and "durability was decreased drastically when attacking enemy corpses, friendly characters etc." ([source](http://www.polygon.com/2015/4/21/8464295/dark-souls-2-weapon-durability-bug-fix-scholar-of-the-first-sin), I'm not sure if the latter issue is linked to the frame rate).

[Dark Souls II](http://steamcommunity.com/app/236430/discussions/0/618459405727869821/) and [Scholar of the First Sin](http://steamcommunity.com/app/335300/discussions/0/611703999983889371/) Steam pages only have an announcement of an "upcoming patch". Has weapon degradation bug been fixed in the both versions?

Comment: It's been a while since I played DS SoTFS, but I think it has not been fixed.

Comment: This is not a "bug" in the exact sense of the word. It is functioning exactly as it was programmed to. The issue is that the higher framerate was not taken into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed.

> The patch is very small and while FromSoftware has not announced it going live, reports on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/355th1/dark_souls_ii_scholar_of_the_first_sin_update/) and [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/app/236430/discussions/0/620712999970547314/) suggest that it does indeed fix the issue.

[Source](https://www.vg247.com/2015/05/08/dark-souls-2-durability-bug-now-fixed/) - dated May 2015.

To note however, that while a lot of players have had issues with the Dark Souls games (especially on PC), FromSoftware have often had a very strong "Deal with it" approach to player complaints, often stating that apparently "buggy" features are working as intended; the latest being the Dark Souls 3 ["poise bug"](http://kotaku.com/from-software-says-dark-souls-3s-seemingly-useless-pois-1776079738).

The reason for this approach is that firstly; the game was developed to be difficult; often phrases like "frustratingly difficult" being used to describe it. After all, the tag line for the series is "Prepare to Die". Secondly; the game was actually developed by the dev team, *for* the dev team*. That is, they developed a game that *they* wanted to play. They created the features *they* wanted, they created the challenges *they* wanted. Effectively, we're actually playing somebody else's game.

*Reference needed.